# LinqToSql converting single C# variable into multiple SQL parameters

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a variable in C# which I am using multiple times in a LinqToSql query.  The generated SQL declares the variable twice, even though it is the same physical variable in C#

The C#

```
const string abc = "ABC";
var test = (from f in DataContext.Foo
            where f.Name == abc || f.Description == abc
            select f.Field1).ToList();
```

The Generated SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Field1]
FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Name] = @p0) OR ([t0].[Description] = @p1)',N'@p0 varchar(3),@p1 varchar(3)',@p0='ABC',@p1='ABC'
```

Noticed that @p0 and @p1 are both 'ABC'.

I have tried making the C# variable a constant to see if that helps but is makes no difference.

Is it possible to make LinqToSql only pass this variable through once, given that it is the same physical variable in C#?  This is only a simple example but in more complicated queries where I am passing through the same variable multiple times I am ending up with a numnber of unnessessary parameters in the SQL.

Please ignore the actual SQL - this is just for an example, it could be any SQL I am just interested in why the parameter is declared twice even through it is the same variable in C#.

Gavin's suggestion using the "let" generated the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t1].[Field1]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Field1], @p0 AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[Name] = [t1].[value]) OR ([t1].[Name] = [t1].[value])',N'@p0 nvarchar(3)',@p0=N'ABC'
```

So the parameter is declared once, but is now using an inner SELECT.

Comment: Why does it matter? Your query is going to be slow no matter what because of the OR condition.

Comment: I don't want the focus to be on the actual SQL - put any SQL you like in there.  The reason for the question is why the parameter is declared twice even though it is the same parameter in C#

Comment: If you are worried about the SQL generated being perfect, you probably shouldn't be using an ORM.

Comment: Yes I guess there is a trade off.

Comment: It creates two parameters because that is the way Entity works. No ORM generates "perfect" SQL and, as @cadrell0 said, if you want perfect SQL, don't use an ORM.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. I don't have anything setup to test it but it might just do the trick.

```
const string abc = "ABC";
var test = (from f in DataContext.Foo
            let search = abc
            where f.Name == search || f.Description == search
            select f.Field1).ToList();
```

Comment: This almost worked - the parameter is declared once, but an inner select is used

Answer (score 1):

That's Linq2Sql for you.

I don't think a few extra parameters will have even a noticeable performance impact on your system.

If you want to improve performance there are probably other parts of your system that you should be looking at.

I'm not saying that the query is perfect (it is not), but you probably shouldn't worry about it.

If you desperately want to get rig of those duplicated parameters than write a stored proc and construct the query manually.

Comment: Thanks - I am getting issues with execution plan caching and re-use so wanted to explore every option.  The actual query in question (not from the example) is much longer and uses the same c# parameter around 15 times so thought it may have an affect on the execution plan